# Draw a surface on a ternary diagram with pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, tikz-3dplot

I'd like to draw a surface on a ternary diagram.

Until now, I can plot density maps on a ternary diagram (cf. [density map](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95499/tikz-pgfplots-ternary-diagram-density-map)).
But I would like to replace the density map by a surface, like [on figs a and b](http://journals.aps.org/prb/article/10.1103/PhysRevB.91.024108/figures/8/medium).

Is it possible to do it with `tikz` - `pgfplots` - `ternaryaxis` - `tikz-3dplot` ?

Answer (score 5):

Regarding the two-dimensional ternary axes in your screen shot: yes, using its `patch` plots:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12} 
\usepgfplotslibrary{ternary}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{ternaryaxis}[
    axis on top,
    xlabel=x,ylabel=y,zlabel=z,
    colorbar]
\addplot3[
    patch,
    shader=interp,
    point meta=\thisrow{C}
] table{
     X Y Z C
     0 0 1  100
     1 0 0  0
     0.5 0.5 0  0

     0.5 0.5 0  0
     0 1 0  20
     0 0 1 100
};
\end{ternaryaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The plot handler expects a series of patches, per default using `patch type=triangle`. In my case, I provided two triangles, and provided the color data in column `C` of the input table.

All other plot handlers should work as well, even `surf` which expects a matrix of input values.

Regarding the three-d visualization: there is no builtin support for such axes.

Comment: Even with a `surf` as an argument of the `addplot3` command, the figure is still 2D, like fig [c and d] (http://journals.aps.org/prb/article/10.1103/PhysRevB.91.024108/figures/8/medium) , but I want to draw figures like fig a and b.

Comment: Ok. As mentioned above: "Regarding the three-d visualization: there is no builtin support for such axes." This is the answer.

Comment: Sorry. I have read your answer too fast. Don't you think the figures I linked are made with pgfplots ?

Comment: No problem! And yes, I am quite sure that the linked figures are not made with pgfplots. If they were, I would happily think about ways to incorporate their solution into `pgfplots`.