# Trouble with pgfplots ternary diagram

Tags: pgfplots

I've been trying to help my wife with a ternary diagram that she needs for her master thesis, but I'm having unexpected trouble with pgfplots. The following code, which I got from an [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/276496/draw-a-surface-on-a-ternary-diagram-with-pgfplots) from Christian Feuersänger himself is not working properly for me. Instead of producing the expected result

[image]

It's producing

[image]

from a copy/paste of the code (running MacTeX 2015, with pdfLaTeX). Changing \pgfplotsset{compat=1.12} to \pgfplotsset{compat=newest} (1.13) does not have any effects.

For convencience, here's the code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12} 
\usepgfplotslibrary{ternary}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{ternaryaxis}[
    axis on top,
    xlabel=x,ylabel=y,zlabel=z,
    colorbar]
\addplot3[
    patch,
    shader=interp,
    point meta=\thisrow{C}
] table{
     X Y Z C
     0 0 1  100
     1 0 0  0
     0.5 0.5 0  0

     0.5 0.5 0  0
     0 1 0  20
     0 0 1 100
};
\end{ternaryaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Any ideas?

Edit: here the result of \listfiles

```
*File List*
standalone.cls    2015/07/15 v1.2 Class to compile TeX sub-files standalone
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
   ifpdf.sty    2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
 ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
 xkeyval.sty    2014/12/03 v2.7a package option processing (HA)
 xkeyval.tex    2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
standalone.cfg    2015/07/15 v1.2 Default configuration file for 'standalone' c
lass
 article.cls    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
pgfplots.sty    2016/01/06 v1.13 Data Visualization (1.13)
    tikz.sty    2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.151)
     pgf.sty    2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.15)
  pgfrcs.sty    2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.31)
everyshi.sty    2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
  pgfrcs.code.tex
 pgfcore.sty    2010/04/11 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.7)
graphicx.sty    2014/10/28 v1.0g Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
graphics.sty    2016/01/03 v1.0q Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2010/04/23 v1.9 graphics configuration of TeX Live
  pdftex.def    2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
  pgfsys.sty    2014/07/09 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.48)
  pgfsys.code.tex
pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex    2013/09/09  (rcs-revision 1.9)
pgfsysprotocol.code.tex    2006/10/16  (rcs-revision 1.4)
  xcolor.sty    2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
 pgfcore.code.tex
pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty    2007/07/03 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.7)
pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty    2007/07/23 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.1)
  pgffor.sty    2013/12/13 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.25)
 pgfkeys.sty    
 pgfkeys.code.tex
 pgfmath.sty    
 pgfmath.code.tex
  pgffor.code.tex
    tikz.code.tex
supp-pdf.mkii
pdftexcmds.sty    2011/11/29 v0.20 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
epstopdf-base.sty    2010/02/09 v2.5 Base part for package epstopdf
  grfext.sty    2010/08/19 v1.1 Manage graphics extensions (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2011/04/07 v1.3 Define keys (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2011/06/30 v3.11 Key value format for package options (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
epstopdf-sys.cfg    2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Live
 ***********
```

My MacTeX 2015 installation is updated daily with CTAN.

Comment: I get the correct result and the same file list (I think). Just to make sure, can you copy the code from your question back to a new file in a clean directory and recompile? Try also compiling from the command line with `TEXMFHOME=/nodirectoryhere pdflatex <filename>.tex`. (If for some reason you have a directory called `nodirectoryhere` at the root level, change the name to something else.) If that still gives the wrong result, can you post the `.log` file somewhere?

Comment: New dry runs, from a clean folder with just the tex file, executed neatly from the terminal, either with \pgfplotsset{compat=1.12} or \pgfplotsset{compat=newest}, with the engines: pdflatex, xelatex and luatex. All aux files erased between runs. Still the same…
I'm starting to think it is system related, I have an older MacBook, stuck on OS X 10.7.5, but as far as I know, there should be no trouble of this kind in the TeX world. Log files were all clean, no errors, not even a warning in any of the runs.

Comment: Maybe it is just a problem with the PDF viewer. What program are you using in which version?

Comment: Apple's Preview 5.5.3 (719.31), which comes with OS X. I'll try and get another to see if it makes a difference. I'll post the response soon.

Comment: Thanks guys! It would appear the built-in preview app is lacking some features. A freshly installed Adobe Reader 10.1 "solved the problem".

Answer (score 1):

The question was answered. This is not related to TeX or even pgfplots, but to the built-in Preview app in OS X 10.7.5 (Lion) which I'm stuck. Using a newer PDF Viewer solves the problem.

Thank you all for your time and suggestions!